# Concurrent execution of QThread or QRunnable objects in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, pyqt

I have the following code:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
import time

class GUI(object):

    IDLIST = [i for i in xrange(20)]
    UNUSEDIDS = [i for i in xrange(20)]

    def __init__(self):
        print "GUI CLASS INITIALIZED!"

        worker = Worker()
        worker2 = Worker2()

        threadpool = QThreadPool()
        threadpool.setMaxThreadCount(10)

        for i in xrange(5):
            #Alternate between the two
            #threadpool.start(worker)
            #worker2.start()


    @classmethod
    def delegator(self):
        """Irrelevant to the question, I need this method for something else"""
        USEDIDS = []

        toUse = self.UNUSEDIDS[0]
        USEDIDS.append(toUse)
        self.UNUSEDIDS.pop(0)

        return toUse


class Worker(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        #idInUse = getattr(GUI, "delegator")
        idInUse = GUI.delegator()
        print "Hello world from QRunnable", idInUse
        #time.sleep(5)

class Worker2(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker2, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        idInUse = GUI.delegator()
        print "Hello world from QThread", idInUse    


s = time.time()
GUI()
print "Done in %s" % ((time.time()-s) * 1000)
```

I think the desired effect is obvious from the code. I want the "Hello world from QThread/QRunnable " to be shown. Since I am writing a multi-threaded application, in my GUI `__init__` part I have the loop that starts concurrent threads.

The thing is that, with QRunnable it works just fine. All the 5 threads I specified get executed at once, concurrently. With QThread, however, that is not the case. Instead, I get the following error:

> QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

And it is not executed at all.

Normally I would not at all mind using the QRunnable, however, it does not derive from QObject (so I can't directly emit signals though I can construct a `QObject()` within it) and also it does not have the `.stop()` method which I badly need. Googling revealed that there is no way to stop a QRunnable from executing? On the other hand, QThread has both of these methods that I need.

So I guess my question is either how to make multiple same QThreads run concurrently, or how to terminate an execution of a QRunnable?

(also please bear in mind that the python's built-in threading module is out of the question)

Answer (score 0):

The `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`-exception happens because you never wait for your threads to finish, and you don't keep any reference to them (neither to `worker`, `worker2` or `threadpool`, so when your `__init__` finishes it gets destroyed.

if you keep a reference to this objects, then is should work:

```
def __init__(self):
    print "GUI CLASS INITIALIZED!"

    self.worker = Worker()
    self.worker2 = Worker2()

    self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
    self.threadpool.setMaxThreadCount(10)

    for i in xrange(5):
        #Alternate between the two
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
        # this is wrong, by the way!
        # you should create 5 workers, not call start 5 times...
        self.worker2.start()
```

and calling the `wait`/`waitForDone` methods on the thread/pool is even better.
For a `QThreadPool` this implicily happens [when it's (C++) destructor is called](http://qt-project.org/doc/qthreadpool.html#dtor.QThreadPool). If that wasn't the case, then your program wouldn't have worked with `QRunnable`s in the first place eiter. For the `QThread` [nothing like this happens](http://qt-project.org/doc/qthread.html#dtor.QThread) and it's even mentioned that it will probably result in a crash. So it's better to explicitly wait for the threads to finish...

also, i hope you already know [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/thread-basics.html)

Comment: The code you provided does work - that's exactly the one I intially used. Even when I keep the references to the objects, the same error still happens. By calling the `QThreadPool()` destructor, I will kill every `QRunnable()` within it - and that's something I don't want. 

If I waited for the thread to finish before starting a new thread, then there's no real point because I want the concurrent execution to take place - not one thread after another.

I also did not call the `QThread()`'s destructor but would rather call its `.terminate()` method, which works fine.

Comment: you don't have to wait for the old thread to finish before starting a new one. you clould for example create 5 or 10 instances in a loop and put them in a list to to keep the references. And you can't call a C++ destructor from python, that happens implicitly when the variable goes out of scope and is garbage collected. you can delete the python objects which will cause the same (and crash probably crash the program for a running QThread).

Comment: Yes like I said, I tried creating instances inside the loop as well, to no avail.